# how to remove duplicate lines from a tex file (or string variable) using a google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a text file in google drive, that is automatically generated, and in the process, duplicated lines are created. I now how to get the content into a string variable.

Is is possible to remove the duplicate lines? I don't mind if the order of the lines is changed or if blanc lines are erased...

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few attempts, i got this

```
function revomeduplicatedlines(string){  
  var array = string.split('\n');
  Logger.log(array);
  var newarray = [];
  newarray.push(array[0]);

  for (var i = 1; i<array.length; i++){
     if (newarray.toString().indexOf(array[i])>=0){
        Logger.log('duplicate line found');
      }      
      else {
        Logger.log('not duplicate line found');
        newarray.push(array[i]);
      }
    }    
  var newstring = newarray.toString().replace(/,/g, '\n');
  return newstring;
  }
```

Is it improvable?

Regards,

Comment: you should probably sort your array before looping because your script can only detect contiguous equal items. ( unless you know for sure all duplicates will be in contiguous rows )

Comment: Hi, your observation seems incorrect. newarray is the array that contains non duplicate lines. In "if (newarray.toString().indexOf(array[i])>=0)", the element array[i] is tested against all previous lines, detecting non only contiguous equal lines, but all of them...

Comment: it's ok, no problem ;)